# Automapper: Ignore on condition of

Tags: c#, automapper

Is it possible to ignore mapping a member depending on the value of a source property?

For example if we have:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

public class CarViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

I'm looking for something like

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CarViewModel, Car>()
      .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, 
      opt => opt.Ignore().If(source => source.Id == 0))
```

So far the only solution I have is too use two different view models and create different mappings for each one.

Answer (score 60, accepted):

The Ignore() feature is strictly for members you never map, as these members are also skipped in configuration validation.  I checked a couple of options, but it doesn't look like things like a custom value resolver will do the trick.

Use the [Condition()](http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html) feature to map the member when the condition is true:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<CarViewModel, Car>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, opt => opt.Condition(source => source.Id != 0))
```

Comment: What's the status of this feature? When can we expect it?

Comment: It's in the nightly release.  You can find it at the teamcity.codebetter.com site.

Comment: @Jimmy Bogard, Can you please guide me to a download link to Automapper.dll containing this feature. Actually, I have been unable to find a release for this feature at the teamcity.codebetter.com site. Thanks in anticipation for the assistance.

Comment: I was happy that this functionality exist, however I soon realized that using it with condition means adding business logic in the mapping section and that all of us should avoid to keep SoC and SRP.

Comment: I use latest production AutoMapper and Skip method doesn't exist.

Comment: I can't see this either and it'd help me greatly with what I'm doing.

Comment: It's Condition instead.

Comment: The following would be a useful addition to Condition: 
.ForMember(dest => dest.MyObjectId, opt => opt.Condition(source => source.MyObject != null, opt.MapFrom(source => source.MyObject.Id)))

Comment: It's just a condition, you have to specify the mapping as well.

For example 

 .ForMember(dest => dest.quantity,
  opts => opts.MapFrom(src => src.Quantity))
  .ForMember(dest => dest.quantity,
  opts => opts.Condition(src => src.Quantity > 0))

Here if Quantity > 0 then Quantity will be set to destination otherwise it will be ignored.

Answer (score 6):

I ran into a similar issue, and while this will overwrite the existing value for `dest.Code` with null, it might be helpful as a starting point:

`AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap().ForMember(dest => dest.Code,config => config.MapFrom(source => source.Id != 0 ? null : source.Code));`

Comment: Nice workaround I hadn't seen myself, but Jimmy's way is still better.

Comment: No, Jimmy's answer doesn't do what the question asks. It simple omits configuration of a field that wasn't configured. So, essentially it does nothing. I am not sure how anyone could uptick that so called solution.

Comment: Jimmy's answer didn't work for me, this one did. I think it's because I was trying to map the source to a complex object if the Id property was NOT 0 like this: `AutoMapper.Mapper.CreateMap().ForMember(dest => dest.MyObject,config => config.MapFrom(source => source.Id != 0 ? source : null));`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the documentation of the conditional mapping:
http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html

There's also another method called PreCondition very useful on certain scenarios since it runs before the source value is resolved in the mapping process:

```c#
Mapper.PreCondition<CarViewModel, Car>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.Code, opt => opt.Condition(source => source.Id == 0))
```