# Override type mapping in AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

I've got the following...

```
Mapper.CreateMap<string, string>().ConvertUsing(x => x.Clean());
```

...but I only want to use this mapping when mapping between *some* types. If this mapping were to be the default, how could I override it for selected types?

Cheers, Ian.

Comment: You mean that you want to map some strings, but not all of them?

Comment: Yes. I think misused the word type. I wanted to call clean() on *some* strings when mapping them but not all.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, new try ;)

Maybe you could use Ignore() If() and Skip() to achieve your goal.
If you can figure out from the string what you should do with it.

Bit like in this question:
[Automapper: Ignore on condition of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451189/automapper-ignore-on-condition-of)

Comment: I think you *can* map from string to string.

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. I just hadn't used it for that. Sorry, my bad.