# Using automapper to apply a filter to a collection

Tags: filter, collections, automapper

I have a domain model that contains a collection and I want to use AutoMapper to map the parent and children to the view model but I don't want children that have been "soft" deleted to be taken across. For instance:

```
public class Customer {
   public EntitySet<Order> {get;set;}
}
public class Order {
   public DateTime? DeletedDate {get;set;}
}
```

my AutoMapper definition would be

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>();
```

and I don't want Orders to be in the view model that have a value for DeletedDate.

Is that possible in AutoMapper? Many thanks in advance,

Steve.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I came across similar issue and finally the approach similar to the one below worked for me:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Orders, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Orders.Where(o => !o.DeletedDate.HasValue)));
```

This assumes your Customer entity and CustomerViewModel dto have collections named "Orders".

Comment: How would we do that if we needed to add a variable. ex. `Where(o=>o.UserId== variableUserId)` ?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like it would be a good fit for a [custom ValueResolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers&referringTitle=Home). It will allow you to do your logic checks in an isolated fashion.  I don't have Visual Studio in front of me right now, but I can add some sample code later if you'd like.

**EDIT**:
After tinkering with this I don't think a ValueResolver is the way to go.  I was able to get it to work by using the following conditional configuration for the `Order` mapping:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Order, OrderViewModel>()
   .ForAllMembers(opt => opt.Condition(src => !src.DeletedDate.HasValue));
```

The only thing with this is that the`OrderViewModel` will *still* come over but it will be `null`.  In other words if you had 3 orders, and one had a deletion date, then the number of orders you will have in your view model will still be 3, but the deleted value will be `null`. I'm guessing it would be best to just have 2, but I'm not seeing a clear way to do that right now.

[Here's a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451189/automapper-ignore-on-condition-of) with a response from the author of AutoMapper that talks about a `Skip` method, but I wasn't able to see that feature in the latest release that I'm using.

Comment: Would you apply the ValueResolver to the map for Customer or for Order?

Comment: Hi, I had also seen that post from the author Jimmy Bogard and attempted to use the Skip extension method but been unable to. Since that post was dated April 2010 perhaps it was subsequently removed?

Comment: Perhaps the answer to this question is that Automapper really is just a mapping tool and shouldn't be used to do some kind of business domain logic. For instance, flattening a structure is okay, but ignoring transforming certain members from a collection is not okay.

Since MVC views are supposed to quite dumb, I'm reluctant to iterate through the Order collection and skip the null ones or the ones with a DeletedDate set. Likewise, I'm not certain of the purity of putting a new method on the CustomerViewModel called GetOrdersNotDeleted.

Comment: @stevie_c: You make a good point.  AutoMapper does apply a convention based mapping to source methods as well--methods that start with `Get*` will be mapped to the corresponding property in your destination (view model).  In this case, you could create a method on your domain object that reads `GetActiveOrders()` and have a view model property that is `ActiveOrders`, and this should map over without any additional configuration.

Comment: Thanks, that's a neat idea. I need to think about that a little bit though because my domain class is actually a Linq2Sql entity. So I could add `GetActiveOrders()` which does something like `return Orders.Where(x => x.RemovedDate == null)` but that will then make that method un-testable (for me currently) because the domain class is using a Sql data context.