# Automapper configuration between two types

Tags: c#, automapper

I have class(its part of it):

```
Filter { string CashierId; }
```

And

```
ClientQuery { IList<Person> Persons; }
```

Where `Person` looks:

```
    Person {
      SolvingPersonIn();
      SolvingPersonIn(string solvingPersonXnuc = null);

      string SolvingPersonXnuc { get; set; }

    }
```

And how I can configure Automapper to map my `Filter` to `ClientQuery`?

Something like this:

```
cashierId = "12345678";
ClientQuery.Persons should be one element with "12345678"
```

Comment: Which property of `Person` shall have the value "12345678"?

Comment: SolvingPersonXnuc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to add a single CashierId to the List of Persons, you can create and populate a new list:

```
CreateMap<Filter, ClientQuery>
        .ForMember(dest => dest.Persons, 
            o => o.ResolveUsing(src => { 
                return new List<Person> { new Person { SolvingPersonXnuc = src.CashierId }};
            })
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

Automapper is an object-object mapper, that means from an object it will convert it to another object. You can apply filter when you are converting data like this in this thread [example our to filtering a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226419/using-automapper-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-collection):

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Customer, CustomerViewModel>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.Orders, 
        opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Orders.Where(o => !o.DeletedDate.HasValue)));
```

You can for example in you case take only the first one or you test your data beforehand then apply your normal mapping.

```
 if (ClientQuery.Persons.Count(x => x.SolvingPersonXnuc) > 1)
 {
    // your logic here when you have more than one person with the CashierId
 }

 // apply your mapping here
```

You can have a read at the official documentation, there are a lot of examples [Automapper documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki)