# How can I ignore list members that are null?

Tags: c#, list, automapper

I am using Automapper to map models in my web app.

I use this Automapper method:

```
protected virtual IEnumerable<TDto> Map(IEnumerable<TModel> models)
{
    return Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TDto>>(models, MappingOptions);
}
```

And I use it in my own method like this:

```
protected override IList<EngineAssembly> GetChildren(Engine parent)
{
    return parent.EngineParts;
}
    
var parent = Session.Get<TParent>(parentId);
if (parent == null) return NotFound();
var children = GetChildren(parent);
return Ok(Map(children));
```

The problem is, sometimes the IList of `children` may contain a null entity. Which causes this error:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException
HResult=0x80131500
Message=Error mapping types.
Source=<Cannot evaluate the exception source>
StackTrace:
<Cannot evaluate the exception stack trace>

Inner Exception 1:
ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
```

But I can't figure out how to weed out any `null` entities that may be in the list of children.

I return a `NotFound` message if a parent is null, but is there a way to just ignore `null` children?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226419/using-automapper-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-collection ?

Comment: @ZiggZagg thanks for finding that!  That should work!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using automapper to apply a filter to a collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6226419/using-automapper-to-apply-a-filter-to-a-collection)