# Automapper "skip" configuration option

Tags: automapper

I am looking for a version of the automapper dll that contains the "skip" configuration option as detailed in the link below:

I have downloaded both ver: 1.1 & 2.0 from github but cannot find this feature.

[Automapper: Ignore on condition of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451189/automapper-ignore-on-condition-of)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a Condition option now:

```
CreateMap<Source, Dest>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.SomeValue, opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Bool));
```

Comment: i tried using that and it seems to not allow multiple instances.

Comment: Multiple instances? If you have a complex condition just indicate it in your Condition. opt => opt.Condition(src => src.Foo || (src.Bar && src.Bax))