# AutoMapper - What's difference between Condition and PreCondition

Tags: c#, automapper

Suppose a mapping using AutoMapper like bellow:

```
mapItem.ForMember(to => to.SomeProperty, from =>
{
    from.Condition(x => ((FromType)x.SourceValue).OtherProperty == "something");
    from.MapFrom(x => x.MyProperty);
});
```

What's difference of substitute Condition by PreCondition:

```
    from.PreCondition(x => ((FromType)x.SourceValue).OtherProperty == "something");
```

What's the practical difference between this two methods?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The diference is that PreCondition is executed before acessing the source value and also the Condition predicate, so in this case, before get the value from **MyProperty** the PreCondition predicate will run, and then the value from property is evaluated and finally Condition is executed.

In the following code you can see this

```cs
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Person, PersonViewModel>()
                .ForMember(p => p.Name, c =>
                {
                    c.Condition(new Func<Person, bool>(person =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Condition");
                        return true;
                    }));
                    c.PreCondition(new Func<Person, bool>(person =>
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("PreCondition");
                        return true;
                    }));
                    c.MapFrom(p => p.Name);
                });
        });

        Mapper.Instance.Map<PersonViewModel>(new Person() { Name = "Alberto" });
    }
}

class Person
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Getting value");
            return _name;
        }
        set { _name = value; }
    }
}

class PersonViewModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

The output from this program is:

```
PreCondition
Getting value
Condition
```

Because the Condition method contains a overload that receives a ResolutionContext instance, that have a property called **SourceValue**, the Condition evaluate the property value from source, to set the SourceValue property on ResolutionContext object.

#### ATTENTION:

This behavior work properly until version <= 4.2.1 and >= 5.2.0.

The versions between 5.1.1 and 5.0.2, the behavior is not working properly anymore.

The output in those versions is:

```
Condition
PreCondition
Getting value
```

Comment: This looks like a bug, can you open a GitHub issue?

Comment: Hi @JimmyBogard its a pleasure to receive your comment, thanks for AutoMapper!! I tried the current version of AutoMapper in GitHub master branch and this is fixed, but in the latests version(5.1.1) this happens, so I guess in the next release of AutoMapper it will be fixed.

Comment: @JimmyBogard the new version 5.2.0 fixed!