# Automapper creates 2 instances of one object

Tags: c#, automapper

My `Company` object has a list of `Employees`, and my `Payroll` object has a list of `Employees`.

In my DTO, let's say `company` and `payroll` both share the same instance of `employee` (there is only one employee object).

When I map them with AutoMapper:

```
        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg => {
            cfg.CreateMap<DTOBusiness, Business>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DTOCompany, Company>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DTOPayRoll, PayRoll>();
            cfg.CreateMap<DTOEmployee, Employee>();
        });

        var business = config.CreateMapper().Map<Business>(dtoBusiness);
```

Two separate instances of that employee object are created, therefore:

```
company.Employee != payRoll.Employee
```

They're identical in properties, but not the same instance.

This makes things very awkward, because these are the same object in the DAL (and need to be the same object in the business layer).

Can I prevent AutoMapper from creating 2 instances of the same object?

Comment: This is just a shot in the dark: have you considered using AutoMapper.Collection (https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Collection) or possibly some other extension (I assume you're using this with an ORM)?

Comment: Good shout but I've actually tried that also (using EqualityComparison on the IDs), but when an object has multiple parents it still seems to create a different instance for each parent.

Comment: Just found this.. mapping based on a condition: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451189/automapper-ignore-on-condition-of).. maybe if `company.Employee == payRoll.Employee` then skip the map?

Comment: The problem is that, to AutoMapper, they are different objects. You really should avoid comparing references like that if possible. Probably better to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set PreserveReferences on your map. It is set automatically for you only to prevent recursion. That's not the case here I suppose. [The docs](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/5.0-Upgrade-Guide#circular-references).

Comment: I don't think this will help here. The instances are actually different.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you! @DavidG In this case before the mapping they're not different, it's just the one instance.