# C# AutoMapper issue with mapping Many-to-Many, wrong foreign key

Tags: c#, automapper

I have faced with the strange issue with mapping model to entity with Many-to-Many relationship

I have the following entities and models:

```cs
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace AutoMapper.ReproducedExample
{
    public class StoreEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<StoreProductEntity> Products { get; set; } = new List<StoreProductEntity>();
    }

    public class ProductEntity
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<StoreProductEntity> Stores { get; set; } = new List<StoreProductEntity>();
    }

    public class StoreProductEntity
    {
        public int StoreId { get; set; }
        public StoreEntity Store { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public ProductEntity Product { get; set; }
    }

    public class StoreModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ProductModel> Products { get; set; } = new List<ProductModel>();
    }

    public class ProductModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<StoreModel> Stores { get; set; } = new List<StoreModel>();
    }

    public class CustomProfile : Profile
    {
        public CustomProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<StoreModel, StoreEntity>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Products,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Products))
                .AfterMap((model, entity) =>
                {
                    foreach (var entityProduct in entity.Products)
                    {
                        entityProduct.StoreId = entity.Id;
                        entityProduct.Store = entity;
                    }
                });
            CreateMap<StoreModel, StoreProductEntity>()
                .ForMember(entity => entity.StoreId, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Id))
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Store, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model))
                .ForMember(entity => entity.ProductId, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Product, opt => opt.Ignore());

            CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductEntity>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Stores,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Stores))
                .AfterMap((model, entity) =>
                {
                    foreach (var entityStore in entity.Stores)
                    {
                        entityStore.ProductId = entity.Id;
                        entityStore.Product = entity;
                    }
                });
            CreateMap<ProductModel, StoreProductEntity>()
                .ForMember(entity => entity.StoreId, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Store, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(entity => entity.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Id))
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Product, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));

        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var configuration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile<CustomProfile>();
            });
#if DEBUG
            configuration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
#endif
            var mapper = configuration.CreateMapper();
            var store0 = new StoreModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Store0",
            };
            var store1 = new StoreModel()
            {
                Id = 2,
                Name = "Store1",
            };
            var product = new ProductModel()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Product",
            };
            store1.Products.Add(product);
            product.Stores.Add(store1);
            store0.Products.Add(product);
            product.Stores.Add(store0);
            
            var store0Entity = mapper.Map<StoreEntity>(store0);
            Debug.Assert(store0Entity.Products[0].Product.Stores[0].Store.Id ==
                         store0Entity.Products[0].Product.Stores[0].Store.Products[0].StoreId);
        }
    }
}
```

Mapping pass successfully, but by some reason some deep key is not mapped to the related `StoreEntity`

The following assertion is failed ...

```cs
Debug.Assert(store0Entity.Products[0].Product.Stores[0].Store.Id ==
             store0Entity.Products[0].Product.Stores[0].Store.Products[0].StoreId);
```

Seems like by some reason in depth Store class AutoMapper uses wrong mapped List ... but I am not sure ...

Comment: Here is also example on github: https://github.com/redradist/AutoMapper.ReproducedExample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out how to fixed this issue (thanks to answer on question [Automapper creates 2 instances of one object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45616878/automapper-creates-2-instances-of-one-object?noredirect=1&lq=1))

For detecting `Circular references` I can add `.PreserveReferences()` method for mapping

Here is proper `CustomProfile`:

```cs
    public class CustomProfile : Profile
    {
        public CustomProfile()
        {
            CreateMap<StoreModel, StoreEntity>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Products,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Products))
                .AfterMap((model, entity) =>
                {
                    foreach (var entityProduct in entity.Products)
                    {
                        entityProduct.StoreId = entity.Id;
                        entityProduct.Store = entity;
                    }
                })
                .PreserveReferences();
            CreateMap<StoreModel, StoreProductEntity>()
                .ForMember(entity => entity.StoreId, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Id))
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Store, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model))
                .ForMember(entity => entity.ProductId, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Product, opt => opt.Ignore());

            CreateMap<ProductModel, ProductEntity>()
                .ForMember(d => d.Stores,
                    opt => opt.MapFrom(s => s.Stores))
                .AfterMap((model, entity) =>
                {
                    foreach (var entityStore in entity.Stores)
                    {
                        entityStore.ProductId = entity.Id;
                        entityStore.Product = entity;
                    }
                })
                .PreserveReferences();
            CreateMap<ProductModel, StoreProductEntity>()
                .ForMember(entity => entity.StoreId, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Store, opt => opt.Ignore())
                .ForMember(entity => entity.ProductId, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.Id))
                .ForMember(entity => entity.Product, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));
        }
    }
```

But actually I did not know if it is an issue or not, because according the documentation AutoMapper should detect [Circular References](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/5.0-Upgrade-Guide.html?highlight=Circular%20references#circular-references) automatically for AutoMapper version 10.0.0 and seems like this is an issue

Comment: @JohnH I always posts solution, if I had one, to helps others no to face with the same issue. It is my help to community

Comment: @JohnH Also I have created issue on github where I started discussion if it is an issue or not https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/issues/3503