# AutoMapper Inline Ignore

Tags: c#, automapper

I am using Auto Mapper to map source to destination object, I have configured my mapper like this:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {    
   cfg.CreateMap< SourceModel, DestModel>();   
}
```

This source and dest object mapping is being used in many places, now in some cases, I have to ignore one of source model field, but not for all places. I could do like this:

```
 CreateMap< SourceModel, DestModel>()
   .ForMember(x => x.CreatedDateTime, opt => opt.Ignore());
```

But this will ignore CreatedDateTime property for all scenario, so I want to do it inline only.

```
 Mapper.Map< DestModel>(sourceObject); //Here I want to ignore one property.
```

Please help me how I can achieve this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automapper: Ignore on condition of](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2451189/automapper-ignore-on-condition-of)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need conditional mapping.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2454385/2401021) answer on SO shows how to use it and the documentation can be found [here](http://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Conditional-mapping.html).

example usage:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<SourceModel, DestModel>()
 .ForMember(dest => dest.CreatedDateTime, opt => opt.Condition(source => source.Id == 0))
```

Comment: Is there any option other than conditional mapping which we can do in inline way only?
Mapper.Map< DestModel>(sourceObject);

Comment: The only other way I can think of is to have two separate destination classes (that inherit from common base) and create a map for each class i.e. on that takes date and one that ignores it. Don't know if this is feasible in the bigger scheme of what you are trying to do.